# Interval functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an function that runs every minute however I want the function to run first then run every minute. How can this be done, my function is below:

JS

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
          //some code
    });

}, 1000 * 60 * 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a named function, or store the function in a variable. Here's how I would do it:

```
function doSomethingWithAjax() {
    $.ajax(...);
}

doSomethingWithAjax();
setInterval(doSomethingWithAjax, 1000 * 60 * 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to creating a named function is to create a function that runs your function *once* then schedules it for execution:

```
function runAndSetInterval(func, millis) {
  func();
  setInterval(func, millis);
}

...

runAndSetInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    // some code
  });
}, 1000 * 60 * 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the function in a variable, pass it to the `setInterval` and then invoke it. Take a look:

```
var intervalFunction = function(){
    $.ajax({
          //some code
    });
};

setInterval(intervalFunction, 1000 * 60 * 1); 
intervalFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be:

```
var callServer = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url'
    }).done(function(data){
        //do something with data
        setTimeout(callServer, 1000);
    });
}
```

Comment: you have omitted to actually call the function in the fist place.  Apart from that, this would be a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to call the function recursively, so the 60 seconds timer only starts after the ajax is done.

```
function functionName(){
    $.ajax({
        //do something
    }).done(function(){
        setTimeout(functionName, 60*1000)
    });
}
```

Then you only have to call this function once at the start of your script.

```
functionName();
```

Comment: With this option I am getting an error that `functionName();` is not a function when I try to call it

Comment: Sorry was in object oriented mode, fixed it.